# Python executable (pyinstaller) throws an error when I close it

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable, fatal-error, python-turtle

I created a basic Pong game with Turtle on Windows, which works pretty well, but every time I close it, it throws an error: 'Fatal error detected: Failed to execute script pong'. I have been looking for a solution prior to ask for help, but I couldn't find a proper answer.

In order to create the .exe file I used 'pyinstaller'. This was the exact command I wrote:

> pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --add-data "bounce.wav;." --add-data "collision.wav;." --add-data "score.wav;." pong.py

This is my code:

```
"""
Basic pong game
"""

import turtle
import winsound

import os
import sys

win = turtle.Screen()
win.title("Pong")
win.bgcolor("black")
win.setup(width=800, height=600)
win.tracer(0)

# Score
score_a = 0
score_b = 0

# Paddle A
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
name_a = "Verde"
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("green")
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-350, 0)

# Paddle B
paddle_b = turtle.Turtle()
name_b = "Amarillo"
paddle_b.speed(0)
paddle_b.shape("square")
paddle_b.color("yellow")
paddle_b.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_b.penup()
paddle_b.goto(350, 0)

# Ball
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape("circle")
ball.color("white")
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0, 0)
ball.dx = 0.15
ball.dy = -0.15

# Pen
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 260)
pen.write("{} 0 | 0 {}".format(name_a, name_b), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

# Functions
def resource_path(relative_path):
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), relative_path)


def paddle_a_up():
    if paddle_a.ycor() < 240:
        y = paddle_a.ycor()
        y += 20
        paddle_a.sety(y)

def paddle_a_down():
    if paddle_a.ycor() > -240:
        y = paddle_a.ycor()
        y -= 20
        paddle_a.sety(y)

def paddle_b_up():
    if paddle_b.ycor() < 240:
        y = paddle_b.ycor()
        y += 20
        paddle_b.sety(y)

def paddle_b_down():
    if paddle_b.ycor() > -240:
        y = paddle_b.ycor()
        y -= 20
        paddle_b.sety(y)

# Keyboard binding
win.listen()
win.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, "w")
win.onkeypress(paddle_a_down, "s")
win.onkeypress(paddle_b_up, "Up")
win.onkeypress(paddle_b_down, "Down")

# Main game loop
while True:
    win.update()

    # Move the ball
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

    # Border checking
    if ball.ycor() > 290:
        winsound.PlaySound(resource_path("bounce.wav"), winsound.SND_ASYNC)
        ball.sety(290)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.ycor() < -290:
        winsound.PlaySound(resource_path("bounce.wav"), winsound.SND_ASYNC)
        ball.sety(-290)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.xcor() > 390:
        winsound.PlaySound(resource_path("score.wav"), winsound.SND_ASYNC)
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1
        score_a += 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("{} {} | {} {}".format(name_a, score_a, score_b, name_b), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

    if ball.xcor() < -390:
        winsound.PlaySound(resource_path("score.wav"), winsound.SND_ASYNC)
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1
        score_b += 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("{} {} | {} {}".format(name_a, score_a, score_b, name_b), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

    # Paddle and ball collisions
    if (ball.xcor() > 340 and ball.xcor() < 350) and (ball.ycor() < paddle_b.ycor() + 50 and ball.ycor() > paddle_b.ycor() - 50):
        winsound.PlaySound(resource_path("collision.wav"), winsound.SND_ASYNC)
        ball.setx(340)
        ball.dx *= -1

    if (ball.xcor() < -340 and ball.xcor() > -350) and (ball.ycor() < paddle_a.ycor() + 50 and ball.ycor() > paddle_a.ycor() - 50):
        winsound.PlaySound(resource_path("collision.wav"), winsound.SND_ASYNC)
        ball.setx(-340)
        ball.dx *= -1
"""
End code
"""
```

I have no clue what may cause that error, since the program runs fine and all the sound effects work correctly.

Thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Hey not sure if you still need help on this but line 103 seems to be causing issues:

```
ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
```

It only occurs when closing the application, like you said.
I'm not sure if there is a proper solution but a bandaid solution you can use to avoid pyinstaller from throwing errors is to wrap the entire while loop in a try/catch.

```
# Main game loop
try:
    while True:
        win.update()

        # Move the ball
        ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
        ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

        # Border checking
        if ball.ycor() > 290:
            winsound.PlaySound(resource_path("bounce.wav"), winsound.SND_ASYNC)
            ball.sety(290)
            ball.dy *= -1

        if ball.ycor() < -290:
            winsound.PlaySound(resource_path("bounce.wav"), winsound.SND_ASYNC)
            ball.sety(-290)
            ball.dy *= -1

        if ball.xcor() > 390:
            winsound.PlaySound(resource_path("score.wav"), winsound.SND_ASYNC)
            ball.goto(0, 0)
            ball.dx *= -1
            score_a += 1
            pen.clear()
            pen.write("{} {} | {} {}".format(name_a, score_a, score_b, name_b), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

        if ball.xcor() < -390:
            winsound.PlaySound(resource_path("score.wav"), winsound.SND_ASYNC)
            ball.goto(0, 0)
            ball.dx *= -1
            score_b += 1
            pen.clear()
            pen.write("{} {} | {} {}".format(name_a, score_a, score_b, name_b), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

        # Paddle and ball collisions
        if (ball.xcor() > 340 and ball.xcor() < 350) and (ball.ycor() < paddle_b.ycor() + 50 and ball.ycor() > paddle_b.ycor() - 50):
            winsound.PlaySound(resource_path("collision.wav"), winsound.SND_ASYNC)
            ball.setx(340)
            ball.dx *= -1

        if (ball.xcor() < -340 and ball.xcor() > -350) and (ball.ycor() < paddle_a.ycor() + 50 and ball.ycor() > paddle_a.ycor() - 50):
            winsound.PlaySound(resource_path("collision.wav"), winsound.SND_ASYNC)
            ball.setx(-340)
            ball.dx *= -1
except Exception:
    sys.exit(0)
```

It's not the best solution I admit, but I hope this helps!